# How to Merge All File in Other Folder into One File and add newline

Tags: text-processing

I have lot of folders and files, this is the structure I have

```
26-09-2016/CHANGELOG_20160926.TXT
26-09-2016/FILE_CHANGELOG_20160926.TXT
27-09-2016/CHANGELOG_20160927.TXT
27-09-2016/FILE_CHANGELOG_20160927.TXT
```

I need the output as follows.
All files with name like `CHANGELOG_*.TXT` shall be merged and add separate new line into one file like `CHANGELOG_20160926-20160930.TXT`, and all file with name `FILE_CHANGELOG_*.TXT` shall be merged and add separate new line into one file too like `FILE_CHANGELOG_20160926-20160930.TXT`.

How can I do that?

Comment: It is not quite clear where you want the newlines. Could you give a small example of what you want, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not specify any language requirement, here's a possibility using Python 3.

```
#/usr/bin/env python3

from glob import glob
from os.path import basename
import re

for prefix in ('CHANGELOG', 'FILE_CHANGELOG'):
    files = dict((int(re.split('[_.]', basename(f))[-2]), f)
                 for f in glob('*-*-*/%s_*.TXT' % prefix))
    out_file = '%s_%d-%d.TXT' % (prefix, min(files.keys()), max(files.keys()))

    with open(out_file, 'w') as f_out:
        for date in sorted(files.keys()):
            with open(files[date]) as f_in:
                for line in f_in:
                    f_out.write(line)
            f_out.write("\n")
```

It basically uses `glob` and `basename` to list and parse file names, sorting them by date. The min/max values are used to build the output filename, and all the files are written there in order. Don't forget to adjust the patterns to your actual directory structure, should it be necessary. Then, just `chmod` and run:

```
$ chmod +x script.py
$ ./script.py
```

Comment: Wow, this is very cool. Thanks for helping. Sorry late give you a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr):

First, let's treat this as a text processing task assuming we have the example list of path names a an input file called `paths`. We transform `paths` into shell commands which `cat` the groups of files together and produce the required output files:

```
@(do
   (defstruct file-info nil
     full-name
     root-name
     date-key
     (:method equal (self) self.date-key)))
@(collect :vars (files))
@  (all)
@dd-@mm-@yyyy/@*{name}_@yyyy@mm@dd.TXT
@  (and)
@path
@  (end)
@  (bind files @(new file-info full-name path root-name name
                     date-key ^(,yyyy ,mm ,dd)))
@(end)
@(do
   (let ((h (group-by (usl root-name) files :equal-based)))
     [hash-update h sort]
     (dohash (name flist h)
       (let ((start (find-min flist))
             (end (find-max flist))
             (paths (mapcar (usl full-name) flist)))
         (put-line `cat @{paths " "} >\ \
                    @{start.root-name}_@{start.date-key ""}- \
                    @{end.date-key ""}.TXT`)))))
```

Run:

```
$ txr catfiles.txr paths
cat 26-09-2016/CHANGELOG_20160926.TXT 27-09-2016/CHANGELOG_20160927.TXT > CHANGELOG_20160926-20160927.TXT
cat 26-09-2016/FILE_CHANGELOG_20160926.TXT 27-09-2016/FILE_CHANGELOG_20160927.TXT > FILE_CHANGELOG_20160926-20160927.TXT
```

To work on real paths and do the `cat` commands requires simple modifications:

```
@(do
   (defstruct file-info nil
     full-name
     root-name
     date-key
     (:method equal (self) self.date-key)))
@(next :list (glob "*/*.TXT"))
@(collect :vars (files))
@  (all)
@dd-@mm-@yyyy/@*{name}_@yyyy@mm@dd.TXT
@  (and)
@path
@  (end)
@  (bind files @(new file-info full-name path root-name name
                     date-key ^(,yyyy ,mm ,dd)))
@(end)
@(do
   (let ((h (group-by (usl root-name) files :equal-based)))
     [hash-update h sort]
     (dohash (name flist h)
       (let ((start (find-min flist))
             (end (find-max flist))
             (paths (mapcar (usl full-name) flist)))
         (sh `cat @{paths " "} >\ \
              @{start.root-name}_@{start.date-key ""}- \
              @{end.date-key ""}.TXT`)))))
```

The only changes are the addition of a `@(next :list (glob "*/*.TXT"))` to redirect the input scanning over a list of paths globbed from the filesystem, and a switch from `put-string` to `sh` to have the `cat` commands executed.

**If the lists of files can be very large, we will run into OS command/argv passing limits: we cannot cat them in a single command.**

A possible fix for that is to change the last part of the code to:

```
@(do
   (let ((h (group-by (usl root-name) files :equal-based)))
     (hash-update h (op sort))
     (dohash (name flist h)
       (let* ((start (find-min flist))
              (end (find-max flist))
              (paths (mapcar (usl full-name) flist))
              (target `@{start.root-name}_@{start.date-key ""}- \
                       @{end.date-key ""}.TXT`))
         (sh `> @target`)
         (each ((group-of-ten (tuples 10 paths)))
           (sh `cat @{group-of-ten " "} >> @target`))))))
```

I.e. for each file, use `> file` to ensure it exists and is truncated to zero. Then use `cat ... >> file` to append the logs to it, in groups of ten.